# Birt reports and Eclipse Html5

Tags: eclipse, html, birt

When I create a report with Birt 4.4.2, it seems impossible to generate the table style in html5. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What have you tried so far?  Adding your code will help you get an answer.

Comment: Basically, the html element in the reports are in html4, like this: <TABLE cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> But I would want it like this : <TABLE style="padding:0px;border-spacing:0px;">

Comment: Because my web application is in html5, I would like to keep it like this for the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

"HTML5" content can be achieved using various options:

- embed the visualization in HTML5 using the BIRT JavaScript API
- generate your own visualization using the BIRT REST API
- link to an external CSS file
- write an HTML5 emitter

Someone seems to have started writing a new HTML5 emitter at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/457537/